# Кроссбраузерный метод предотвращения случайного выхода из страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Использую beforeunload, в опере 12.14 не работает, ничего не показывает и переходит на другую страницу.
а в файрфоксе 29.0  выскакивает алерт, а на заднем фоне меняется страница.
В хроме и сафари работает отлично. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кроссбраузерно?

[image]

```
$( window )
.off( 'beforeunload' )
.on( 'beforeunload', function () {
   alert( 'beforeunload' );
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.event.add(window, 'beforeunload', function () {
   return "Вы куда?";
});
```

P.S. Опера плохо поддерживаеи beforeunload.

Comment: старая опера вообще не поддерживает это событие =) вот интересная статейка http://habrahabr.ru/post/141793/